# How cross platform is bash scripting?

Tags: macos, cross-platform

I have been bash scripting for about 10 years now so I'm pretty comfortable with it, my primary language was PHP but I started learning python (and I'm really glad I did, this is by far my favourite language) and I really like how it can work together with bash. I've started learning to write GUI apps but I don't want to write apps solely for linux users. What I'm wondering is if I can use my bash scripting skills for writing code that will work on Mac OSX, Android and iOS. Windows

When I say bash scripting skills, I'm also referring to my understanding of the infrastructure of the operating system and how to interact with it. Like for example, the donf database on linux systems is a useful way to configure the systen, but Mac OSX doesn't have a dconf database. However, OSX must have something similar that would make the scripts be easy to adapt. Windows is pretty alien compared to unix based systems.

I often find it useful to add some bash into my python scripts, to run commands like find, or ps, and also tools that don't come prepacked with linux like mat or nmap. Does this destroy the possibility of the app being cross platform?

For building GUI apps with python, I have a lot of choices on frameworks I can use. I started with KiVy because I read that its best for cross platform apps but is that really the case? Would a more universal framwork like GTK not beSo what I'm wondering is how useful my shell scripting experience and experience with linux might be for writing apps for OSX, Android and iOS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Writing a Bash script can get the job done very quickly on a Linux machine, but it won't work on a Windows machine.